# Transactional email template styling missing magento 2

Tags: php, css, email, magento, styling

I'm having a problem with my Magento 2 transactional emails in particular the product listing. In my local environment it looks like this which in my personal opinion its the way its supposed to:
[image]

I just made a new email template which using the "new order for guest (magento/luma) template.

When i use my online testenvironment. It shows me the following order email styling:[image]

i did no coding, just made a new email template with the standard layout and set it at stores > configuration > sales > sales emails

PS. I already changed the settings that the order summary only shows excl. TAX, but the styling is still different.

**Edit**

I concluded that when i do a clean installtion it will give me the normal email (image 2) template. I even tried to set my theme back to luma (cause i used a custom theme) and even disabled all my custom modules. it still shows me the wrong styling! I am really getting confused.

Comment: Did you copy the CSS part?

Comment: Depends on which "css part" you mean, i am using a custom theme.